# Dart webapp - download file to a temporary directory

Tags: dart

I'm working on a web-app that requires downloading large files from a server (rendering 3d models).

```
void getStlFile() {
  client.get(
    "127.0.0.1:3456/my-stl-file",
  ).then((http.Response response) async {
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        // bytes are here -> response.bodyBytes

        // create a new file from the bytes

        var path = ''; // get the path from the new file 

        onSuccess(path);
        break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  });
}
```

I've already looked into https://www.dartlang.org/dart-vm/dart-by-example, but as you can see, `dart:io` does not work in browsers.

Is there a browser equivalent?

An alternative solution would be loading the stl file into the three.js scene without having a resource path---aka, load the stl file as a binary blob. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-html/HttpRequest-class.html available in the browser. 
Also WebSocket is available for the browser.